# JIRA: How to show Epics with the status "In Progress" in the Kanban board?

Tags: jira, tools

When using the KANBAN board on JIRA, and I change the status of an EPIC to IN PROGRESS (either changing the status through the status field or moving the card to the "IN PROGRESS" column), the respective card disappears from the board. I still can see them through filters, in the issues view, but not in the kanban board.

Does anyone know why that happen?

And is there a way to show those EPICS in the IN PROGRESS column/status from the KANBAN board?

Comment: You don't seem to actually have a question, here. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Why is it that you need an Epic to display as In Progress? Also, what type of board are you talking about? Scrum Active Sprint? Kanban? Simple Issue Tracking?

Comment: Seconded Sarov's comment. Plus, we did not observe this with the many epics we have in progress: be it in Kanban, or Active Sprint view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Kanban board has a mapping of statuses to columns (in the board configuration).

It is possible that you have no column that is mapped to the "In Progress" status.

That means that any issue with a status of "In Progress" will not appear on the board.

It is also possible that you have a trigger associated with the transition to "In Progress" that is doing something that might make the epic invisible.

Comment: The only other notable cause could be the saved filter the board is based on. If, for whatever reason, the board's JQL is written in a way that ignores "In Progress" epics, that'll break them, too.

But 9/10 times, it's column mappings, as you say.